# Parse Facebook Login Error: "You must initialize FacebookUtils before calling logIn"

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, parse-platform

I am trying to use Facebook login on Parse with cordova.

```
$cordovaFacebook.login(['email'], function(response) {

Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn('email', {
    success: function(user) {
        console.log('success fb login')
        // Handle successful login
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
        // Handle errors and cancellation
        console.error(error)
    }
});

}, function(error) {
console.error(error)
});
```

And in a `.run` block on `app.js`, I have

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
    appId: fbAppId,
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: true,
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    version: 'v2.4'
});
FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
console.log('Parse FB loaded')

// loadParse()
};
```

However, on the logger when I run the app on my iOS device, I never see a "Parse FB loaded". When I run it on a browser, I **do** see the "Parse FB Loaded".

Whenever I try to login via Facebook on my device, I get the error `You must initialize FacebookUtils before calling logIn`.

I believe the issue is that Parse is not initing FacebookUtils when on a device, but it is on the browser. Why would this be? Would it be an issue with the `window` object?

Note that the Facebook login itself **is** working (through the whole FB login flow), but after the callback to login via Parse with FacebookUtils, I receive the described error.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check this https://gist.github.com/kevincobain2000/63d88024513eb56df058

Answer (score 1):

try this... before to FacebookUtils

```js
  parse.initialize('APPLICATION_ID', 'JAVASCRIPT_KEY');
  parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';

  parse.FacebookUtils.init({ // this line replaces FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxx', // Facebook App ID
    status     : true,  // check Facebook Login status
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
    xfbml      : true,  // initialize Facebook social plugins on the page
    version    : 'v2.12'//point to the latest Facebook Graph API version
  });
```

Comment: Describe a little bit more what is wrong or what are you not understanding.